# JOIN ON SQL syntax

Tags: sql, inner-join

I am taking my first database class and need some info on what I need to change for my script to process. Currently I have 2 tables, an "orders" table and a "customers" table and this is how they are coded.

```
CREATE TABLE customers (
  customer_id           INT          ,
  customer_first_name   VARCHAR(20),
  customer_last_name    VARCHAR(20)     NOT NULL,
  customer_address      VARCHAR(50)    NOT NULL,
  customer_city         VARCHAR(20)     NOT NULL,
  customer_state        CHAR(2)         NOT NULL,
  customer_zip          CHAR(5)     NOT NULL,
  customer_phone        CHAR(10)     NOT NULL,
  customer_fax          CHAR(10),
  CONSTRAINT customers_pk 
    PRIMARY KEY (customer_id)
);

CREATE TABLE order (
  order_id          INT         NOT NULL,
  customer_id       INT         NOT NULL,
  order_date        DATE        NOT NULL,
  shipped_date      DATE,
  employee_id       INT,
  CONSTRAINT orders_pk
    PRIMARY KEY (order_id),
  CONSTRAINT orders_fk_customers
    FOREIGN KEY (customer_id) REFERENCES customers (customer_id),
  CONSTRAINT orders_fk_employees
    FOREIGN KEY (employee_id) REFERENCES employees (employee_id)
);
```

My script to join these two tables together is as follows:

```
SELECT or.order_id, or.order_date, or.customer_city,
    cu.customer_first_name, cu.customer_last_name
  FROM orders or INNER JOIN customers cu
  ON or.customer_first_name = cu.customer_first_name
  AND or.customer_last_name = cu.customer_last_name;
```

Now obviously, I know it is incorrect and may have multiple errors, so be gentle. I would love to know what I can do to make it work. Please advise.

Comment: You shouldn't alias with key words (or). You can tell by the syntax highlighting if it's a key word.

Comment: Use a and b as aliases instead

Comment: @DanielMarcus That is funny but I'm not sure someone just learning SQL will understand the joke so might be good to add a \s.

Comment: You did a really good thing here by providing the code to generate the tables you had questions about. Too many times, that courtesy isn't extended, which is why I upvoted your question. It's a good habit to get into early in your SQL career. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two things:

- Don't use `or` as an alias. That's a reserved word.
- Join by the foreign key.

The query should look like:

```
SELECT o.order_id, o.order_date, cu.customer_city, 
    cu.customer_first_name, cu.customer_last_name
  FROM orders o
  INNER JOIN customers cu 
    on o.customer_id = cu.customer_id
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I added the ';' to the end of the script, however, it unfortunately did not work. If it's any consolation, I am using EDUPE for this.

Comment: What do you mean by "did not work"? Does it show an error, or does it show a wrong result?

Comment: It gives an error: Failed to execute SQL : SQL SELECT o.order_id, o.order_date, o.customer_city, cu.customer_first_name, cu.customer_last_name FROM orders o INNER JOIN customers cu on o.customer_id = cu.customer_id; failed : Unknown column 'o.customer_city' in 'field list'

Comment: Fixed it. The `customer_city` column is in the `customers` table. Try again.

Answer (score 2):

You can join your tables on the ID numbers, and you won't have to worry about what happens when multiple people have the same name.

Use this instead:

```
FROM orders ord INNER JOIN customers cu
ON ord.order_id = cu.customer_id
```

Your select statement can remain as it is. I also re-aliased according to the comment from Error_2646.

Using a field that is a primary key in one of your tables is also better practice than using non-key fields, when possible.